# How to write vertical text from bottom to top without using transform rotate?

Tags: html, css, d3.js

With `writing-mode` you can only get the text to be read from top to bottom. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

the only option I have is using `sideways`. But this attribute is experimental.

```
.verticalTxt_lr {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
.verticalTxt_rl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
.rotate {
  transform: rotateZ(270deg);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/5ueopnqu/2/

I wanted to write the label on the bars to be vertical but it should start from the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/3HL4a/2402/

Trying with rotate gives me a weird behaviour when animating the bar chart therefore I'm looking for another method to create vertical texts that can be read with your head tilted to the left.

Comment: Occam's razor says: do you really really need to animate the bar chart?

Comment: @MrLister: 1) Who or what is Occam's razor? 2) Yes!

Comment: to answer your question: Occam's razor: ask yourself if it's neccesary to have?/if it's adding something valueable to the user's experience, if yes, go for it. if no, you're wasting your time, as well as the user's time

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I combined `writing-mode` and `rotation`:

```css
    .rotated {
        writing-mode: tb-rl;
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="rotated">Text from bottom with working width/height</div>
```

This works for me without bad `width` and `height` settings inside table cells.

---

important 2020 edit:

step 1) Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode , ctrl/cmd-F for "Result". This table will reflect your browser (which may have improper implementation). Look at the table immediately below it. That table is what things *should* look like.

Solution:

To make sure your solution is future proof:

1. Look at the appropriate column, which will be "Horizontal Script" unless you're coding e.g. in an Asian language.
2. Find a row that suits your needs in terms of sizing the HTML element, AND is properly implemented (appears roughly the same) in the second table below it. For example `writing-mode:vertical-rl;` would currently work on Chrome until others are properly implemented in the Blink engine (but if you based your answer off of `sideways-lr` it would break once Blink properly implements this behavior, since the two rows are not the same.).
3. optional: set `transform-origin` to something, maybe use `calc(...)`, based on percentages and/or something else
4. perform `transform:rotate(180deg)` or something. This should fix issues with layout that most people would have, causing them to look up this answer. If one has animation problems, that's a separate issue.

(also tb-rl is deprecated now)

Comment: Any reason for -180 instead of 180?

Comment: In short: `writing-mode: vertical-rl; transform: rotate(-180deg);` gives intended result in 2020!

Comment: The question explicitly asks for an answer without `transform: rotate`.

Comment: `transform: rotate()` also rotates borders. Any workaround?

Answer (score 9):

```css
.rotated {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotated">Text from bottom with working width/height</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this reverses the order of lines in multiline text

Answer (score 2):

```
.rotate {
     transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

This should be enough to rotate text vertically from bottom to top, apply it on div containing the text. If you are using writing-mode: vertical-rl/lr in conjunction to this, that may be switching it to other way around.