# Table column rotated but how to position the rotated cell.

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple table. I want table column to rotate. That's why I have added a class text-flip. It will rotate the column data. But I want to change Cell 1, Cell 2 width based on column data width (after rotate). Like thebelow picture-

[image]

Here column data size may be change.

```css
body{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.text-flip{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 1</td>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 2</td>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 3</td>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 4</td>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 5</td>                           </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by combining [writing-mode with a rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205702/how-to-write-vertical-text-from-bottom-to-top-without-using-transform-rotate) to achieve vertical text. You'll also need to add the class to a `div` instead of the `td`.

Edge will treat the height of the `div` as though it was 100% width, making it take up the full height of the table, so we can add `display: inline-block` to make it only take up as much space as needed.

```css
body{
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.text-flip{
  display: inline-block;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ><div class="text-flip">Column Data 1</div></td>
      <td><div class="text-flip">Column Data 2</div></td>
      <td><div class="text-flip">Column Data 3</div></td>
      <td><div class="text-flip">Column Data 4</div></td>
      <td><div class="text-flip">Column Data 5</div></td>     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But in edge the height (after rotate column, its width is height) of the column is very long.

Comment: Edited answer to add `display: inline-block` for Edge

Answer (score 2):

You could use `writing-mode` if you can spare IE/Edge and Safari

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

```css
body{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.text-flip{
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 1</td>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 2</td>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 3</td>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 4</td>
        <td class="text-flip">Column Data 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would have used `sideways-lr`. In fact, I was about to post that as an answer until I found it only worked in  FF.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :-

```css
body{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.text-flip {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 120px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.text-flip > div {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 30px;
}
.text-flip > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-flip"><div><span>Column Data 1</span></div></td>
        <td class="text-flip"><div><span>Column Data 2</span></div></td>
        <td class="text-flip"><div><span>Column Data 3</span></div></td>
        <td class="text-flip"><div><span>Column Data 4</span></div></td>
        <td class="text-flip"><div><span>Column Data 5</span></div></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```